# Как подняться на следующий уровень пирамиды?

Tags: java

Создаю пирамиду из блоков. Cейчас синий цвет перекрашивает красный. Также не могу понять, как подняться на следующий уровень пирамиды.

```
package cs520.hw4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Legos1 extends JFrame {
    
    public int startX;
    public int startY;
    public int legoWidth;
    public int legoHeight;
    public int baseLenght;
    
    public Legos1()
    {
        super("Iuliia's LEGO's");
        startX = 20;
        startY = 300;
        legoWidth = 50;
        legoHeight = 20;
        baseLenght = 10;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        int i;
        int j;
        int x;
        int y;
        int k;

        for(i = 0; i < baseLenght; i++) {
            
            for(j = 1; j < baseLenght;j++) 
            {   
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                x = (startX + (i*legoWidth));
                y = (startY + (legoHeight));
                g.fillRoundRect(x, y, legoWidth, legoHeight, 2, 2); 
                
            for(k = 1; k< baseLenght;k++) {
                
                x = (startX + (i*legoWidth));
                y = (startY + (legoHeight));
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.fillRoundRect(x, y, legoWidth, legoHeight, 2, 2); 
            }
            
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String\[\] args)
    {
        Legos1 app = new Legos1();
        app.setSize(550, 325);
        app.setVisible(true);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    }
    
}
```

Пример, как должно получиться:

[image: изображение]

Comment: Выглядит красиво. А как надо? И что надо? [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1463670/edit) детали в вопрос, в текущем виде ваш вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: На картинке это пример как нужно сделать. У меня пока получается только или красные или только синие блоки. Плюс я не могу понять как перейти на следующий уровень.

Answer (score 0):

При выводе строки сделайте чередование блоков. Самый простой способ через промежуточный флаг. Пример на основе вашего кода:

```
    boolean isRed = true;  // флаг который будет показывать, какой блок нужно вывести

    for (i = 0; i < baseLenght; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < baseLenght; j++) {
            
            if(isRed) {  // очередь красного блока
                paintBlock(g, i, j, Color.red);
                isRed = false; // следующий синий
            }
            else { // очередь синего блока
                paintBlock(g, i, j, Color.blue);
                isRed = true; // следующий красный
            }
```

При этом что бы не запутаться в коде, вынесите вывод блока в отдельный метод:

```
    private void paintBlock(Graphics g, int i, int j, Color color) {
      g.setColor(color);
      int x = (startX + (i * legoWidth));
      int y = (startY + (legoHeight));
      g.fillRoundRect(x, y, legoWidth, legoHeight, 2, 2);
    }
```

Также вы что то напутали с циклами, по идее j - количество блоков в строке, i - количество рядов. Для построения пирамиды, вам после вывода каждого ряда необходимо вычислять смещение для startX и startY относительно предыдущей строки и уменьшать количество блоков в строке на -1.